# How to trigger a only-css modal with js

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, bourbon

I'm using Refills by Bourbon modals, and are great. But, now that I need to trigger by JS the modal, I don't know how to do it, since it's pure CSS and doesn't have any docs or JS methods.

**The modal is only CSS3:**

```
<div class="modal">
  <label for="modal-1">
    <div class="btn js-btn">Click for Modal</div>
  </label>
  <input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
  <div class="modal-window">
    <div class="modal-inner">
      <label class="modal-close" for="modal-1"></label>
      <h1>Modal Title</h1>
      <p class="intro">Intro text lorem ipsum dolor sit ametm, quas, eaque facilis aliquid cupiditate tempora cumque ipsum accusantium illo modi commodi  minima.</p>
      <p class="body">Body text lorem ipsum dolor ipsum dolor sit sit possimus amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, placeat, explicabo, veniam quos aperiam molestias eriam molestias molestiae suscipit ipsum enim quasi sit possimus quod atque nobis voluptas earum odit accusamus quibusdam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.modal {
  $modal-padding: 3em;
  $modal-background: $base-background-color;
  $modal-close-color: $light-gray;
  $modal-image-height: 135px;
  $modal-image-width: $modal-image-height;

  label {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  label img {
    $img-width: 300px;
    border-radius: $img-width/2;
    display: block;
    max-width: $img-width;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
  }

  .btn {
    @include button(simple, $base-background-color);
    font-size: $base-font-size;
    margin-bottom: $base-line-height;
  }

  .modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .modal-window { // overlay
    @include transition(opacity .25s ease);
    @include position(fixed, 0px 0px 0px 0px);
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .85);
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 99999999999;

    .modal-bg {
      @include position(absolute, 0px 0px 0px 0px);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  .modal-close {
    @include position(absolute, ($modal-padding /2) ($modal-padding /2) 0 0);
    @include size(1.5em);
    cursor: pointer;
    background: $modal-background;

    &:after,
    &:before {
      @include position(absolute, 3px 3px 0 50%);
      @include transform(rotate(45deg));
      @include size(.15em 1.5em);
      background: $modal-close-color;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
    }

    &:hover:after,
    &:hover:before {
      background: darken($modal-close-color, 10);
    }

    &:before {
      @include transform(rotate(-45deg));
    }
  }

  .modal-inner {
    @include transition(opacity .25s ease);
    border-radius: $base-border-radius;
    background: $modal-background;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 95%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 95%;
    padding: $modal-padding /2;
    margin-top: .6em;

    @include media($medium-screen) {
      padding: $modal-padding;
      width: 60%;
      max-height: 60%;
      margin-top: 10em;
    }

    @include media($large-screen) {
      width: 50%;
      margin-top: 10em;
    }

    h1 {
      color: $base-font-color;
      margin-bottom: .6em;
      text-align: left;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    p.body, p.intro {
      font-size: $base-font-size;
      max-width: 100% !important;
      text-align: left;

      &.intro {
        color: $blue;
        line-height: 1.6em;
      }

      &.body { 
        color: $base-font-color;
        line-height: 1.45em;

        @include media($medium-screen) {
          @include columns(2 8em);
        }
      }
    }

    a.cta {
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: .5em;
      margin-top: 1em;

      &:last-child {
        padding: 0 2em;
      }
    }
  }

  .modal-state:checked + .modal-window {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .modal-state:checked + .modal-window .modal-inner {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

I need to trigger it to open when a user clicks a button.

**First: User clicks button and goes to routes**

```
<%= link_to "Guardar en spotbook".html_safe, photo_album_modal_path(@photo.id), remote: true %>
```

**Second: Routes point to the controller action**

```
get    '/photo/:id/album-modal', to: 'photos#albums_add_modal', as: :photo_album_modal
```

**Third: It responds with a js**

```
def albums_add_modal
    @albums = current_user.albums.includes(:photos).reverse_order
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

**Fourth: It will append some html to a div in the view**

```
$("#modal-open").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'add_to_album_modal') %>");
$("#modal-open").HERE SHOULD BE A METHOD TO OPEN THE MODAL, BUT SINCE ITS CSS3-ONLY I DON'T KNOW HOW TO TRIGGER IT.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be triggering the click

```
$("#modal-1").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

I triggered the checked-state from the modal by JS.

```
$("#modal").prop("checked", true);
```